# UISwitch set on/off Image

Tags: xcode, swift, uiswitch

I want to set my Switch like this:

[image]

But I try in ios9 , it does not work.
I saw in apple UISwitch Class Reference.
It says that :

Discussion
In iOS 7, this property has no effect.

How about iOS 9? Any one success?

My Code:

```
switch1 = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - 20, 400, 10, 100))
switch1.on = true
switch1.onTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
switch1.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
switch1.thumbTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

//set on/off image

```
switch1.onImage = UIImage(named: "on-switch")
switch1.offImage = UIImage(named: "off-switch")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a `UIButton` instead.

```
let switchButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
switchButton.selected = true
switchButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "on-switch"), forState: .Selected)
switchButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "off-switch"), forState: .Normal)
```

Use `switchButton.isSelected` instead of `switch1.on`. You'll have to toggle `switchButton.isSelected` when it is tapped, which you can do like this:

```
switchButton.isSelected.toggle()
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! It's a bit misleading to have the UISwitch onImage and offImage in Auto Layout, without any warning.

Comment: Wish i bumped into this earlier instead of spending ages trying to use 3rd party library or doing my own ahah, works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS 1**3, you could do this way:

```
   let switcher = UISwitch()
    switcher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .valueChanged)
    

 @objc func pressed(sender: UISwitch) {
        let color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: sender.isOn ? "on.png": "off.png")!)
        if sender.isOn {
            sender.onTintColor = color
        } else {
            sender.tintColor = color
            sender.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
```

NOTE: your image should look like:

[image]

Then the final result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question, but if you want a completely custom button switch programmatically (that you can add text to), this will work too:

```
 import UIKit

 class RDHiddenVisibleButton: UIButton {

    // Hidden / Visible Button Function
    var isOn = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initButton()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initButton()
    }

    func initButton() {
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.borderColor = Colors.radiusGreen.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2

        setTitleColor(Colors.radiusGreen, for: .normal)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(RDHiddenVisibleButton.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

@objc func buttonPressed() {
        activateButton(bool: !isOn)
    }

    func activateButton(bool: Bool) {

        isOn = bool

        let color = bool ? Colors.radiusGreen : .clear
        let title = bool ? "Hidden" : "Visible"
        let titleColor = bool ? . white : Colors.radiusGreen

        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(titleColor, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```